# Hiding an element works immediately on Firefox but not Chrome/Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to hide/show an element on the beginning of my function. On firefox the element was successfully hidden/show(before the alert command), but on Chrome and Edge the element hides only after the function is complete. I tried "style.display = none/block" but still getting the same result

```
$("#viewbtn").click(function() {
  $("#divMyTable").hide();
  $("#divLoadingScreen").show();
  alert('Check if divMyTable is hidden');
});
```

Comment: alert() is a poor debugging tool. It blocks everything in the page. Try using console.log() instead or wrap the alert in a very short setTimeout and you will see the hide/show occur cross browser

Comment: console.log() shows that the element is already hidden. I also tried to pause the process for 10 sec but during the wait time the element is still showing on my page.

Comment: You seem to be describing a different issue now. Is it or is it not working consistently in the various browsers?

Comment: On firefox its hidden immediately but on edge/chrome the whole function needs to be completed first before it gets hidden. Visually, the element is still showing on the page but console.log says its already hidden.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces this behavior

Comment: Please see demo here  --> https://jsfiddle.net/67ktc4by/3/

Comment: On chrome/edge:
 - wait 10 sec then execute hide and log command.
 
On firefox:
 - execute log command, wait for 10 sec then execute hide command.

Comment: Wrap the while loop in setTimeout and you will see the difference. The style display property is changing but the browser still has to do the "paint" to render the update. That while loop also blocks everything during it's execution. Using a setTimeout allows the paint to occur before the loop starts and blocks everything

Comment: Nice, that solved my problem. Thnk you very much charlietfl

Answer (score -1):

You can use the visibility property. It is used to hide or show the content of HTML elements. The visibility property specifies that the element is currently visible on the page. The ‘hidden’ value can be used to hide the element. This hides the element but does not remove the space taken by the element.

```
.container {
            height: 80px;
            width: 250px;
            border: 2px solid black;
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
        }
```

```
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <button onclick="showElement()">
            Show Element
    </button>
 
    <button onclick="hideElement()">
            Hide Element
    </button>
```

```
       function showElement() {
           element = document.querySelector('.container');
           element.style.visibility = 'visible';
       }

       function hideElement() {
           element = document.querySelector('.container');
           element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
       }
```

Comment: I also tried "visibility=hidden" but still got the same result. Element is only hidden after the function hideElemet() is completed.